# Add parameter to product name for it to show in clickonce installer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm building an application that uses a clickonce installer.
Is there a way to add a parameter to the Product Name (the one displayed in the installer) so it adds the application version next to the name?

Something like `<ProductName>AppName (Version)</ProductName>`??